# Ubuntu 20.04 issue with xrdp and monitor

Tags: xrdp

### Problem

My moniter is black with a single mouse cursor when I connect it with a monitor through DP after I connected to it by xrdp.

Also, xrdp screen will also be black after I connected it with a monitor.

When I reboot, the situation will change between the above two.

What can I do to fix this?

### Versions

xrdp 0.9.12

Linux version 5.4.0-52-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-060) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020

### Monitor

ASUS TUF-VG27AQL1A

Answer (score 0):

In what conditions are you able to actually see with the monitor? Do you have ssh installed and have you tried remoting in? Linux auto detects graphics now but you can manually set it like they did 20 years ago. Boot into recovery mode, run X -configure, cop the new file from /root/xorg.conf.new to /etc/X11/xorg.conf, then you can edit your xorg.conf. Now when you create the xorg.conf file you will have to know specific information about your graphics card and your resolution etc that is out of scope of this question and particular to you setup.